# ROS message sent but not received

Tags: ros, rostopic--pub, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS in my project and I need to send one message from time to time. I have this function:

```
void RosNetwork::sendMessage(string msg, string channel) {
    _mtx.lock();
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = _n.advertise<std_msgs::String>(channel.c_str(),10);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    std_msgs::String msgToSend;
    msgToSend.data = msg.c_str();
    chatter_pub.publish(msgToSend);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    cout << "Message Sent" << endl;
    _mtx.unlock();
}
```

And I have this in python:

```
def callbackFirst(data):
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)
    print("Received message from first filter")

def callbackSecond(data):
    #rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + "I heard %s", data.data)
    print("Received message from second filter")

def listener():
    rospy.Subscriber("FirstTaskFilter", String, callbackFirst)
    print("subscribed to FirstTaskFilter")
    rospy.Subscriber("SecondTaskFilter", String, callbackSecond)
    print("subscribed to SecondTaskFilter")
    rospy.spin()
```

The listener is a thread in python.
I get to the function `sendMessage` (I see in the terminal "Message Sent" a lot of times) but I don't see that the python script receives the message.

Update: I tested the python callback with `rostopic pub /FirstTaskFilter std_msgs/String "test"` and this works perfectly.

Any thought?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215197/ros-message-sent-but-not-received/) by [jdorfsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21544/jdorfsman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-04**:
Well, what is the topic of the Publisher?
Check with `rosnode info <YOUR_PUBLISHER_NODE>` which topics it sends. I guess this is a simple remapping issue...

You can also visualize this with `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use advertise() only once at startup, not every time you want to send a message.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdorfsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/21544/jdorfsman/) on 2015-08-04**:
Thanks, I did that and that solved it.